# How to convert HTMLCollection to Array - Performance Point of View for around 50 Items

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, htmlcollection

I am trying to develop a reusable accordion component where I have to find all the accordion items which are giving me HTMLCollection which seems like an Array form but if you go and try to manipulate with some methods like `forEach` then you will get an error.

I am looking for the easiest and most optimized way around fixing such issues while using pure JavaScript.

Code example:

#### HTML

```
<div classs="container">
    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
        <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
        <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var accordion_el = document.getElementById("accordionExample"),
    accordion_items = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-item");

// below code will give error
accordion_items.forEach(function (item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

I tried with `toArray()` but that failed.

#### What worked for me:

- `Array.from()`
- Similarly, `[...document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-item")]` too

I have a question about the *best performance optimization* to take a minimum time for the DOM manipulation if have multiple instances of the same component on a page.

Comment: try `Array.from(...)`

Comment: @DanielA.White, @lusc: Oh, both `Array.from()` and spread-operator are working well for my purpose but as I am developing a reusable component for a CMS which one would be good to consider for better performance sake?

Comment: as for performance - test. in the end it wouldn't likely matter that much

Comment: @DanielA.White, I think it would while the component is instantiable. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use spread syntax to convert to an array.

```js
accordion_items = [...document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-item")];
```

However, you can directly use `document.querySelectorAll` here, which returns a `NodeList` that has a `forEach` method.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-item").forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
  <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
  <div class="accordion-item">...</div>
</div>
```